Failed to unmount oldroot
When updating nvidia driver to version 560 on ubuntu 22, i get black screen with error failed to unmount oldroot/sys ...
Driver or resource busy, and it doesn't shutdown.
I tried to downgrade the driver to version 535, and adding some commands to grub setting file then sudo update-grup didn't solve the problem.

As written there is no info here that can be used to offer any help. Ubuntu 22 would be a version of Ubuntu Core as that is the only version of Ubuntu to only use a 2 digit version number. If that is not what you are using please edit the question and add the actual version. Also please add the exact steps you did to remove the old version of the driver and the steps you used to install the new driver. Add what are the exact commands you added to grub.
